# Can an OS utilize all 4 nodes (4 x 2(22 core) CPUs=176 cores) in a server rack like C6320?

Tags: dell, rack

Are the 4 nodes in the C6320 utilized as 4 different sets of CPUs in a hypervisor?Or can they be all used under one OS?

Can all of them being used in a 22 x 8 = 176 core system in say Windows?

Comment: 8 socket x86 systems exist, but that Dell is not one of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They will be 4 independent servers needing to run a separate OS each.